# "File not found" error when clicking on stories

Tags: ee2

I'm working on reviving (and upgrading the EE 3)n a site that has been moribund (no posting) for about 18 months.  The home page index displays OK, but if I click on any story or try to view the next page of the index, I get a blank page with the message "File not found."

I don't know when the site stopped working. It's running EE version 2.10.1. The back end and control panel seem to work fine.

The site is at http://coastsider.com

Any idea what might be going on here?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer.  In the .htaccess file, I'm rewriting URL's to remove the index.php file. When my sysadmin updated Apache, I needed to change:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

to

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

That information is in the .htaccess file comments as well. I hope that save someone else some time.